# Java Sending KeyEvent Insert key using Robot class

Tags: java, insert, keypress, awtrobot, key-events

I want to programmatically send two <kbd>Insert</kbd> key events: one for the keypad insert key, and the other for the other insert key on the keyboard.

I've done the following, but this only allows me to send one of the two:

```
Robot bo = new Robot();
bo.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_INSERT);
```

How can I send both, separately?

Comment: What do you mean by the another "INSERT" button?

Comment: like left shift and the right shift we have two insert buttons in the keyboard